# How to configure forever in nodeclipse?

Tags: node.js, eclipse-plugin, monitoring, forever, nodeclipse

I have installed **"Enide Studio 2014"** on Windows 7. Then I created an **"Node.js Express Project"**. Everything went smoothly, a new project was created. I was able to run it without any problems.

As stopping and starting node server everytime I make any changes in the code takes unnecessary efort while developing, I wanted eclipse to **"monitor"** changes and restart node accordingly. As nodeclipse provides an option for this purpose, I tried to configure **forever** as node monitor.

In **Nodeclipse preferences** Node Path was set as "D:\Software\Development\NodeJS\node.exe" as it should be. Forever was installed in **"D:\Software\Development\NodeJS\node_modules\forever\bin\forever"** so I set **"Node monitor path"** in as that.

After this I was not able to run the project again.

When I check console output, the command issued (and failed) was:

```
node D:\Software\Development\NodeJS\node_modules\forever\bin\forever D:\calismaalani\nodejs\deneme\app.js
```

I copied the command line and issued it on the command window myself and got:

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script D:\Software\Development\NodeJS\D:\calismaalani\nodejs\deneme\app.js does not exist.
```

As it is clearly seen, Nodeclipse was trying to add node_home path to the absolute path for my app. I have tried to set some environment variables but could not manage to get the right path for my app.

What is wrong here? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Since Nodeclipse 0.17 Run with Node monitor is [hidden](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/commit/56b25428e8beef679f9eec9d5f9db51ff4d11ee4) as it raised more questions then solved.

Please launch via CLI as `forever` and [TCF-Terminal](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tcf-terminals) is nice shell integration into Eclipse,
so you can have several forever instances running for different project in separate tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the "Node options" path in Nodeclipse preferences as `D:\Software\Development\NodeJS\node_modules\forever\bin\forever --sourceDir .` and Nodeclipse should automatically use forever to start your node Js application.

I use nodeclipse version 1.0.2.x and use nodemon to monitor the application and it works fine for me.

**Edit:**
In your case, you cannot pass the absolute path to **forever** . if you need to ,you can use the "--sourceDir . " option of forever. The --sourceDir and the "." option looks for the full path of the application. So your command will look as follows:

```
node D:\Software\Development\NodeJS\node_modules\forever\bin\forever --sourceDir . D:\calismaalani\nodejs\deneme\app.js
```

You need to give **Node monitor path** as  `D:\Software\Development\NodeJS\node_modules\forever\bin\forever --sourceDir .`

Incase you are using **nodemon**, you need to give the path as `C:\Users\ashwin_valento\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js --watch`